# How to connect via SSL over Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, security, ssl

There is a website I want to go to, and the URL looks like this - 
irc://dsadfasdfgweh.onion:2525
No that is not a real website, I am not giving away the actual website I am trying to access. How do I connect to this? whenever I do, it tries to download a file, and if I click yes, nothing downloads.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a web site, that is IRC (internet relay chat). You need an IRC client to connect to it. http://www.irc-junkie.org/2009-12-31/howto-irc-anonymously-with-tor/ might help you with IRC over TOR.

Comment: I can't watch videos over tor, but I will look into Xchat

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Tor acts like a tunnel, so - use SOCKS ot transproxying JUST to connect as usual : with SSL or via IRC... There should be no obstracle in Tor layer itself.